# What does 'kill -0' (kill dash zero) option do in a while loop?

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, signals

I got to write bash script that expands `cp` giving copying speed and ETA. In the internet I found script that used `while kill -0 $pid; do` loop. It works for me, but I can't quite understand why it works. What does `-0` option do.

My script goes like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp $1 $2 &
pid=$!
trap "kill $pid 2> /dev/null" EXIT

olddst_size=0

sleep 1

while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null; do

    src_size=$(ls -l $1 | cut -d " " -f5)
    dst_size=$(ls -l $2 | cut -d " " -f5)

    diff_size=$(($src_size - $dst_size))

    # Speed in MB/s

    speed=$(bc -l <<< "scale=4;$(($dst_size-$olddst_size))")
    olddst_size=$dst_size

    #ETA

    eta=$(bc -l <<< "scale=0;($diff_size/$speed)")

    echo -ne "                                                          "\\r

    echo -ne "Copying speed:" $speed "B/s" "ETA:" $eta "s"\\r

    sleep 1

done
echo -ne "                                                         "\\r`
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you specify a signal to send to a process as the argument to `kill`. `-0` has a special meaning - it doesn't send a signal, it just checks the process is still running.

---

Relevant parts from `man kill`:

```
NAME
       kill - terminate a process

SYNOPSIS
       kill  [-signal|-s  signal|-p]  [-q  value] [-a] [--timeout mil‐
       liseconds signal] [--] pid|name...
       kill -l [number] | -L

DESCRIPTION
       The command kill sends the specified signal  to  the  specified
       processes or process groups.

       [..]

       If signal is 0, then no actual signal is sent, but error check‐
       ing is still performed.
```

The `[-signal|-s  signal|-p]` part is confusing but the gist is that

```
kill -0
```

can only mean

```
kill -s 0
kill --signal 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! This is the perfect example of when reading the manual is not enough (and confusing even). Without your explanation I would have never figured out that what `-0` actually does.